# React useEffect and setInterval

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, use-effect

I'm making a React dashboard that calls an API every minute for updates. Following the many answers in SO, I have this at the moment that sort of works:

```
const Dashboard = (props) => {
  const [stockData, setStockData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //running the api call on first render/refresh 
    getAPIData();
    //running the api call every one minute
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
     getAPIData()
    }, 60000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
  
  //the api data call
  const getAPIData = async () => {
    try {
      const stdata = await DataService.getStockData();
      setStockData(stdata);
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

However I keep getting browser warning

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getAPIData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
```

Is this a cause for concern (e.g. causing memory leaks)?

Ive tried to fix it:

- It doesnt seem possible to not use useEffect (use setInterval directly)
- If I remove dependency or put stockData as dependency for useEffect,
  I'll see the API call being made every second, so I assume thats not
  right.
- If I put the api data call block directly in useEffect, the page wont
  have the data shown when it loads the first time/or the page refreshed and I have to wait
  for a minute.

I found several references on the issue such as
[here](https://blog.davidvassallo.me/2020/04/09/react-hooks-and-setinterval/)
and
[here](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)
but I couldn't comprehend it given that I've only started using React
a month ago.

Appreciate any help for this!

Comment: You need to include getAPIData in the [ ] in the useEffect function

Comment: @AhmedAlhameli I put that with UseCallback per Anees Hikmat Abu Hmiad answer below and it seems to fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can resolve this issue in multiple way:

1. You can put getApiData in useEffect direct and use it...
   [image]
2. You can use useCallBack, useEffect is go to re-render and make mempry leeek issue since every time react render Dashboard its re-create the getAPIData, you can prevent this case by using useCallBack, and you must make sure about dependency, just you need to put what you need...for example:
   [image]

Comment: I tried both methods and they work! Am going to stick to the second one following your advice. Cheers!

Comment: Just note to be the point is clear, both solution is good, and just keep in note that any function you want to declare in component must be a useCallBack to improvement it and prevent re-render issue in any where if its need to use as a dependency...